# Make toggleClass animate like slideToggle?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a list that displays the first 3 list items with a link to expand/collapse the list. If the list has 3 items or less then the expand/collapse link does not show.

The problem I have is with the animation when the list expands/collapses. Instead of fading in, I'd like to have the list slide in similar to how a slideToggle works. Unfortunately I can't get that to work with my code.

Does anyone have any suggestions? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Below is my code and here is my Codepen. https://codepen.io/anon/pen/OwGKog

**HTML**

```
<div id="feature-list">

  <ul id="product-features">
    <li>Feature 1</li>
    <li>Feature 2</li>
    <li>Feature 3</li>
    <li>Feature 4</li>  
    <li>Feature 5</li>
    <li>Feature 6</li>  
  </ul>

  <span id="feature-more">More Features</span>
  <span id="feature-less">Less Features</span>

</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#feature-list li:nth-child(n+4) {
    display: none;
}

#feature-list.open li:nth-child(n+4) {
    display: list-item;
}

#feature-more,
#feature-less {
    color: blue;
    display: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

**JS**

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('#feature-list #feature-more').on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).closest('#feature-list').toggleClass('open');
        $('#feature-more').hide();
        $('#feature-less').show();
    });
    $('#feature-list #feature-less').on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).closest('#feature-list').toggleClass('open');
        $('#feature-less').hide();
        $('#feature-more').show();
    });
    if ($('#feature-list > ul > li').length > 3) {
        $('#feature-more').show();
    }  
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, this seems to do the trick.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
$('#feature-list #feature-more').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('ul li:gt(2)').slideToggle();
    $('#feature-more').hide();
    $('#feature-less').show();
});
$('#feature-list #feature-less').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('ul li:gt(2)').slideToggle();
    $('#feature-less').hide();
    $('#feature-more').show();
});
if ($('#feature-list > ul > li').length > 3) {
    $('#feature-more').show();
}  
});
```